# Oracle active and innactive sessions are there even after system down

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am working with java web application which use hibernate 3. And proxool for connection pooling. It mainly dose file uploading and the approximate load will be 2000 file uploads by about 300 users per hour. And the load is getting higher some times. I am facing a trouble of having high number of active and inactive sessions in oracle side and even after the system(wildfly server) down, the sessions stays as they were. 
I have checked the code and it always close the hibernate session in finally block. 
My actual problem is when sessions in oracle side get increase and my application can't get database connections after a while.

my proxool file is as follow

```
<proxool>
      <alias>piokms-conn</alias>
      <driver-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1521:orcl64</driver-url>  
      <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
      <driver-properties>
            <property name="user" value="test" />
            <property name="password" value="test" />
      </driver-properties>
      <autocommit>false</autocommit>
      <simultaneous-build-throttle>150</simultaneous-build-throttle>
      <minimum-connection-count>200</minimum-connection-count>
      <maximum-connection-count>800</maximum-connection-count>
      <maximum-connection-lifetime>1200000</maximum-connection-lifetime> 
      <maximum-active-time>600000</maximum-active-time>
      <house-keeping-test-sql>SELECT 1 From DUAL</house-keeping-test-sql>
      <statistics>5m,15m,1d</statistics>
      <statistics-log-level>ERROR</statistics-log-level>
      <fatal-sql-exception>Connection is closed,SQLSTATE=08003,Error opening socket. SQLSTATE=08S01,SQLSTATE=08S01</fatal-sql-exception>
      <fatal-sql-exception-wrapper-class>org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.FatalRuntimeException</fatal-sql-exception-wrapper-class>
      <verbose>false</verbose>
      <trace>true</trace>
 </proxool>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also I am not familiar with `proxool` itself, your description reminded my of behaviours observered with different frameworks where the `connection pool` was not properly terminated.

According to the [documentation](http://proxool.sourceforge.net/servlets.html) you have two options:

1. Using the `ServletConfigurator`
2. Or manually calling the [`shutdown`](http://proxool.sourceforge.net/api/org/logicalcobwebs/proxool/ProxoolFacade.html#shutdown(int)) method, when your sever terminates.

To verify this problem just shutdown your application and monitor oracle to check whether the number of active sessions goes down to the normal value.

---

> I have checked the code and it always close the hibernate session in finally block.

I assume you want to express that the connection is returned to the pool, which itself only helps you in terms that the connections are not leaking. They are normally not closed at this point of time.

Comment: even when the system is idle (No operations happen and server is running)  more than 300 active sessions from the application server can be seen 'SELECT username, machine, program, STATUS
FROM v$session
WHERE type = 'USER' and status='ACTIVE'. I have no idea how active sessions are running when the system is idle. And I will manually run the shutdown method when the server terminate. Thanks

Comment: You claim you have around `300 users per hour`. If we assume all those active session belong to your application and they are at least active (open) for 20 minutes (according to your configuration) the numbers are matching. You might want to read up about how database connection pooling works in general.